# Cannot access properties by 'this'

Tags: javascript, scope, this, private

In the following snippet I try to access the property `offset` from within the member function `shift()`. As it seems, I cannot access it this way, because `console.log` reports `Offset: NaN`:

```
function shiftImg() {
  this.offset = 0;
  this.shift =
    function() {
      this.offset++;
      console.log("Offset: " + this.offset);
    };
}

productImg = new shiftImg;
window.setInterval(productImg.shift, 100);
```

However, converting the code above from a template paradigm to a closure paradigm works as I'd expect:

```
function shiftImg() {
  var offset = 0;
  return {
    shift: function() {
      offset++;
      console.log("Offset: " + offset);
    }
  }
}

productImg = shiftImg();
window.setInterval(productImg.shift, 100);
```

In my first example, why I cannot access `offset` via the operator `this`?

---

**My Answer:** 
I'll post here my solution, as I cannot append a standalone answer.
Browsing again into the mess of the horribly-written MDN's documentation, I learned of the `bind` method:

```
function shiftImg() {
  this.offset = 0;
  this.shift =
    function() {
      this.offset++;
      var img = document.getElementById('img');
      img.style.paddingLeft = this.offset + 'px';
      console.log("Offset: " + this.offset);
    };
}

productImg = new shiftImg;
window.setInterval(productImg.shift.bind(productImg), 100);
```

Comment: You only lose the scope when it is passed to setInterval: http://jsfiddle.net/F8cJc/ which is caused by the fact that when you pass a function reference to setInterval, it gets executed with `window` as the context unless you use `.bind`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nested function doesn't have it's own `this` context (it'll simply refer to the `window`), so assign a variable to the `this` method within `shiftImg` to which you can refer in the nested function:

```
function shiftImg() {
  var self = this;
  this.offset = 0;
  this.shift =
    function() {
      self.offset++;
      console.log("Offset: " + self.offset);
    };
}

productImg = new shiftImg();
window.setInterval(productImg.shift, 100);
```

The reason you need to do this is because the call to `setInterval` which invokes the method, is run in a separate execution context, where `this` is equal to the `window`. If you called `this.shift()` from within `shiftImg()` you'll see that you it works just fine without the need to add `self`. [See this MDN article for more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout#The_.22this.22_problem).

Alternatively you pass an anonymous function to the callback method in `setInterval`:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    productImg.shift();
}, 100);
```

If you use objects and jQuery then you'll find into this problem quite a lot, and jQuery's [`$.proxy`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) utility method makes doing similar things to above fairly easy.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?

Comment: Is this a generic "problem" affecting every case of nested functions, or does this happen specifically only for `window.setInterval()` ?

Comment: Instead of using the `self` variable, would `bind()` be more appropriate, as shown on the bottom of my edited question?

Comment: Updated my answer, hope that helps @davide :)

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, the context of this for the offset is not the same context as shiftImage. The second function closure changes the scope of this.

Comment: it's actually a reference to `window`

Comment: So it is a problem of scope. Then, how would I access `offset` from the method function?

Comment: @KevinB - ah yes, you're right. I didn't see that 'new' was omitted. I've edited and removed that part.

Comment: @davide - Ian's answer above shows you how to do this, you save a reference to the scope (the variable 'self') and use that instead.